# Link to a specific mail in Outlook 365

Tags: outlook-365

When I read a mail in Outlook 365, I would like to put a link to that specific mail in my external to-do list in order to open it directly.

It's possible with Gmail but I don't see how to do that with Outlook 365.

Is that possible?